# iOS - How to convert m4a to mp3?

Tags: ios, mp3, m4a

I have searched through many websites on the internet, but there's no sample code for converting m4a to mp3.
Does anyone know how to do this in iOS? Thank~

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVAudioFile` to read the m4a, and another `AVAudioFile` to write the mp3 with appropriate format settings. But [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549023/iphone-app-recording-audio-in-mp3) suggests mp3 encoding in iOS is not possible with CoreAudio.