# iOS 7 m4a to mp3 encoding - is it possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, lame

I've searched through all the internet and didn't find a clear answer on my question - How do you record an `m4a` file (because as [this answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319482/1313939) iOS doesn't support mp3 recording) and later convert it to `mp3`?

Recording an audio file seemed to be a piece of cake, but then the nightmare began.

It's 2013 around and I haven't found any clear example of this procedure on the web. [Some people say you can't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562628/1313939) because of some GPL license. [Others suggest to use Apple's examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062157/ios-how-to-convert-m4a-to-mp3) which never ever mentions mp3 at all! There's also [a famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005598/looking-for-a-way-to-encode-mp3-on-iphone) on SO dating back to 2009 one of the answers to which says -

> No difference on iOS: App Store apps aren't allowed to load dylibs.

There's also trouble getting hold of the actual LAME library on iOS - [this question's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207063/how-can-i-compile-lame-as-static-library-a-for-armv6-and-armv7-of-iphone) read that people have trouble compiling it on iOS 6 and above.

With iOS 7 out in the open I would like to raise the question again - is there any example of a sample project I can find that **actually** does deal with mp3 conversion on an iOS device?

Note that this question is not a duplicate of the aforementioned questions and is just an effort to clarify things out. Finally it all comes to the one and final question -

**Is iOS m4a to mp3 conversion possible?**

Comment: It should be possible - there is a similar app that does that: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mp3-recorder-free/id548031942?mt=8

Comment: @GuntisTreulands that's a nice example, but are you sure the app doesn't encode mp3 files on the server side?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I downloaded the app, turned airplane mode:on, recorded a sound, connected phone to mac, opened iExplorer app to access applications data, opened MP3 Recorder app Documents directory and I can see there is a recording I made - qwerty.mp3

Comment: @GuntisTreulands Thanks for the hint, I'll be looking on for more details. So it is possible, that sounds great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I could research it - the closest we can get to it is to convert `Linear PCM` input reordered from the microphone to `MP3`. It has lots of downsides as of the time of the conversion to the huge size of the `.caf` file. You can check out the [project here](http://code4app.net/ios/iOSMp3Recorder/50cb35556803fac31c000000).