# How to record speex format audio file?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I've searched supported format audio files but I've found below formats only.

```
kAudioFormatLinearPCM               = 'lpcm',
kAudioFormatAC3                     = 'ac-3',
kAudioFormat60958AC3                = 'cac3',
kAudioFormatAppleIMA4               = 'ima4',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC                = 'aac ',
kAudioFormatMPEG4CELP               = 'celp',
kAudioFormatMPEG4HVXC               = 'hvxc',
kAudioFormatMPEG4TwinVQ             = 'twvq',
kAudioFormatMACE3                   = 'MAC3',
kAudioFormatMACE6                   = 'MAC6',
kAudioFormatULaw                    = 'ulaw',
kAudioFormatALaw                    = 'alaw',
kAudioFormatQDesign                 = 'QDMC',
kAudioFormatQDesign2                = 'QDM2',
kAudioFormatQUALCOMM                = 'Qclp',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer1              = '.mp1',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2              = '.mp2',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3              = '.mp3',
kAudioFormatTimeCode                = 'time',
kAudioFormatMIDIStream              = 'midi',
kAudioFormatParameterValueStream    = 'apvs',
kAudioFormatAppleLossless           = 'alac',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE             = 'aach',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_LD             = 'aacl',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD            = 'aace',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD_SBR        = 'aacf',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD_V2         = 'aacg',    
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE_V2          = 'aacp',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_Spatial        = 'aacs',
kAudioFormatAMR                     = 'samr',
kAudioFormatAudible                 = 'AUDB',
kAudioFormatiLBC                    = 'ilbc',
kAudioFormatDVIIntelIMA             = 0x6D730011,
kAudioFormatMicrosoftGSM            = 0x6D730031,
kAudioFormatAES3                    = 'aes3'
```

I want to record audio file in format of **speex**, because It's just enough to record speech. Is it possible with `core audio framework`?

**Ref:** I've found [this lib](http://code4app.net/ios/Speex-Audio-compress/52139e0a6803fa4503000000). But It is too complicating process. I want to use simple control with `AVAudioPlayer or AVAudioRecorder.`

Comment: You will have to use the library you found since Apple did not include the `speex` audio codec.

Comment: thank you @rckoenes. I can record with `aac`, `ilbc`.. etc. format. But when we record with `speex`, size is too low. So Only I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 2):

I once had an experience where I had to [record audio with mp3 format on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975421/ios-7-m4a-to-mp3-encoding-is-it-possible). As you can see, it is not listed in your list. I ended up using `LinearPCM` and then converting it to `mp3`. I think this pattern is the only one you need. No standard methods will help you here, as well as I'm concerned.

Recording in any other format than `aac` is a lot of pain on the iOS.

Comment: thank you friend. I can record with aac. I take it into account, But I need to reduce size because this is speech file. `aac` file is 5 times larger than `speex` and `ilbc` format. So only I try to find out this. Any way +1 for you :)

Comment: @Mani Well, recording with arc takes about 45 megabytes for 30 minutes. And don't forget you can actually reduce the quality oа audio recording for low or set your own custom bit rate. Try it out to reduce the size.

Comment: Ya. I already reduce to min Sample bit rate and min audio bit rate, that's why I get that (just 5 time than). Otherwise I'll get too large file.

Answer (score 1):

I've used **OGG Vorbis** for audio playing which is same as **OGG Speex**.. for this i used a library available here on [IDZAQAudioPlayer](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer)…

For OGG Speex audio Recording, I once used this library [OGGSpeex](https://github.com/jcccn/OggSpeex)

If u need further info for implementing it or anything else feel free to ask..

To Really reduce the size of audio recording you can use `AudioFormat : MPEG4AAC` which creates a **135KB file for 60 seconds recording**..

Sure.. **`Code for AAC Recording`**

```
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

    AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
```

Comment: Could you post setting for AAC? I'm using AAC setting, but It's size 200KB for 60 seconds?