# M4A audio files conversion to MP3 or WAV

Tags: ios, dictation

I have developed a native IOS app for doctors who dictate their report. currently the audio files are available in m4a format. However on our servers accepts mp3 or wav audio files. What would be the best way for me to convert the m4a file within the IOS device before the recording is sent towards the dictation server?

Comment: I think your question could be better answered at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This has been ask a few times before.  You cannot use Core Audio to record in mp3 format.  You can use a library call `lame` to help encode though.  http://lame.sourceforge.net

Possible duplicate posts:

- [iOS Code to Convert m4a to WAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738133/ios-code-to-convert-m4a-to-wav)
- [iOS - How to convert m4a to mp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062157/ios-how-to-convert-m4a-to-mp3)

If you're familiar with Objective-C, I wrote a small library utilizing lame and JZRecorder a while back. [DCAudioRecord](https://github.com/derekjcarter/DCAudioRecord)